# How will I open xlsx File in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, excel, import-from-excel

I want to open xlsx File in C#.NET, but it shows error .

But if the file is xls extension then easily i can open it but when file format is xlsx then shows error.

My code is

```
oXL.Workbooks.Open(Path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,
               //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0)
```

The exception is:

> Excel cannot open the file 'New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx'
>   because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that
>   the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches
>   the format of the file.

Comment: Can you specify "shows error" pls?

Comment: I can recommend the following library for XLSX: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: You have Microsoft.Office.Interop version issue. Check if your version supports XLSX. Also, Microsoft.Office.Interop requires MS Office to be installed... which version of MS Office you are using? Can you open that XLSX file in Excel where you are running your programme?

Comment: Make sure you can open the file normally in Excel without any error.

Comment: Interop code can't open a corrupt file. Can you open the same file using Excel directly? Is it a proper `xlsx` file or eg a csv or html file masquerading as `xlsx`?

Comment: Which Excel version do you have installed? Is your version actually able to open `xlsx` files (ie 2007+)?

Answer (score 2):

`Workbooks.Open` will fail if you have a version of Excel in your machine that can't read `xlsx` files (eg Excel 2003).

If you don't need actually Office Interop (so if you just need to read and write files and not use Excel functionalities) then you should take a look at the Office Open XML SDK (v2.5 for .Net 4.5 and v2.0 for .Net 3.5) at [the official download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

You're then able to open an excel file like this:

```
SpreadsheetDocument ExcelDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FileName, false);
```

and perform read and write operations.

To be clear:
The Office Open XML SDK allows for read- and write operations on an Excel (and other Office XML) files, but if you require MS Excel do perform calculations or macros, then this will not solve your issue.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal the SDK can do both.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. If the file is corrupt, the SDK won't be able to open it either

Comment: The OP said that he can open .xls files but not .xlsx files, so from the information he gave I assume it is a version incompatibility issue from the MS Excel product version he is automating with his code.

Comment: You should put that in the answer then. On the other hand, a corrupt file is just as likely.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal calculations have nothing to do with the OP's question. The problem is that the OP can't open the file at all. The probable causes are : corrupt file, fake file or wrong Excel version